# Update fails. Can't install any software !

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic

I did `sudo apt-get update`

```
Reading package lists... Error!                                                
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

When I try to install any software, it gives the same error like:

```
sudo apt-get install gnumeric
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened
```

.

I opened synaptic package error, it gives the same error on startup.

I tried

```
sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get dpkg --configure -a
```

I am still stuck. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Issue this command:

```
 sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf && sudo apt-get update
```

It will fix your problem.

Comment: apt-get update still with error for me, ubuntu 16.04.
Чтение списков пакетов… Ошибка!
E: Malformed 3rd word in the Status line
E: Произошла ошибка во время обработки gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (UsePackage3)
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/status
E: Списки пакетов или файл состояния не могут быть открыты или прочитаны.